# Can't install Ubuntu on SSD due to partitioning issue

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I recently bought a SSD and cloned my windows partition using EaseUS tool. I left some space unallocated in order to install Ubuntu.

The last step in the installation is choosing if you prefer deleting the information in your disk or doing <kbd>Something else</kbd>. I choose this option but it can't load the partition manager and the installer stops working. I have tried more than 10 times and all the times happened the same.

I guess it is some problem in the disk configuration, so already  installed `gparted` and created an `ext4` partition, but it has solved nothing.

Things I have checked:

- my disk is not dynamic
- Machine is is in AHCI mode
- I have deactivated hibernation
- reinstalled Windows from scratch...

And Ubuntu still does not recognize the installation.

The kernel version is `4.18.0-15-generic` and the output to `sudo parted --list` is:

```
sudo parted --list
Model: ATA WDC WDS500G2B0A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted
```

In one of the ~20 tries I have done I could access the partition manager during installation, it said the ssd was 500 GB but only showed a 120 MB partition that occupied 100% percent of the space, really weird:

[image]

Comment: @tatsu Do you know can I make ubuntu recognise the Windows installation? I created the bootable usb downloading the iso and using the Rufus software writing in ISO image mode.

Comment: @tatsu How and why *the Ubuntu fares much better ... if all of the disk is occupied by the Windows partition?* This is illogical.

Comment: @gontxomde There are only a few situations where the installer can't recognize the Windows installation: 1. An unsupported SATA mode - should be AHCI, 2. Dynamic Volumes has been enabled in Windows, 3. The Windows partitions are "dirty" (corrupt) or hybernated due to Fast Startup, 4. The installer was booted in a different mode (UEFI/Legacy).

Comment: @tatsu Sure, but is it better (or different) than reserving unallocated space? The reason why almost everybody recommends shrinking Windows partitions from Windows is because Windows, not Ubuntu. And because since Windows 8 there's a thing called Fast Startup enabled by default there's a risk of making Windows unbootable if its partitions are touched from outside. This is why the OP did it right - the problem is one of the situations I mentioned above - and your rant here is unhelpful and only adds confusion.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have completely reinstalled windows, my ssd is in AHCI mode, dynamic volumes are disabled, I have disabled hibernation and my boot mode was UEFI. The installer says "This computer currently has Windows Boot Manager on it. What would you like to do?" But the option tatsu mentioned does not appear.

Comment: @gontxomde Right now ignore that rant ;) So, it appears that everything is correct, maybe it's asking if you want to proceed with the installation in UEFI mode, just confirm. Is there any other problem?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** We need more info like exact kernel version, the output to `parted --list` ... so please [edit] your question as now **it's unclear what you're asking...**.

Comment: @Fabby Thank you!! I have added the two things you mentioned. Anything else you need please tell me, as I'm very noob in this world

Comment: Many systems, even new, need UEFI update & SSD firmware update to work. Do you have most current versions of firmware from vendors for your hardware?

Comment: I was using ubuntu without a problem until I changed to a SSD. Were you talking about the ssd firmware?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance: favour returned: Question upvoted.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EaseUS has botched your partition table and Ubuntu is not even able to read it as per your output of `parted --list`. That Windows is still able to boot is a small miracle but luckily for you, you saw this early on and I'm expecting huge problems if you continue to use the machine in this state.

As you've just reinstalled Windows 10 anyway, do the following in the following order:

1. Boot Ubuntu Live
2. Open `gparted`

   - <kbd>Device</kbd>
   - <kbd>Create Partition Table</kbd>
   - Choose `GPT`
3. Reboot and install Windows (yeah, again)
4. Boot Ubuntu Live again.
5. Use `gparted` to make space for Ubuntu (no need for third-party tools, you're the second one today that botched his system with EaseUS)
6. Reboot and [install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you, it has finally worked and I have been able to install Ubuntu correctly after weeks. The solution has involved a Windows reinstall but I hadn't got many documents.

Comment: You're welcome. @gontxomde When (re-)partitioning just use a [`gparted live`](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) USB drive when you don't have the Ubuntu Live one lying around: much more reliable than some commercial software...